# "matricular" y "matricularme"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Both the captioned words mean "enroll, register".
"matricular" is a transitive verb and "matricularse" is a reflexive verb.
But they have no difference in meaning but just "matricular" follows a noun and "matricularse" needs the reflexive pronouns, right?
Could you please provide an example for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually more like:

- *matricularse* — to enroll or register oneself
- *marticuar* — to enroll or register someone else or something

*Me matriculé en el curso.* — I've enrolled for the class.

*Matriculé mi coche.* — I've registered my car.

Answer (score 5):

Matricular has 3 meanings:

> [matricular](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?LEMA=matricular).
>
> 1. tr. Inscribir o hacer inscribir el nombre de alguien en la matrícula.
> 2. tr. Inscribir un vehículo en el registro oficial de un país o demarcación.
> 3. prnl. Dicho de una persona: Hacer que inscriban su nombre en la matrícula.

The **first** one is to register the name of somebody to take part in an event. It is typically used for academic events like courses or subjects.

> La secretaria matriculó a María Pérez ayer.

almost the same meaning is the **third** one (which is used in a pronominal way). In that case you're stating that the person is registered (though we don't know who registered the person).

> Me he matriculado en Cálculo Avanzado I

if I say that it means that my name is registered in that subject, but it can be that I registered by myself (for example by doing it in a website) or I just went to the office and asked there to be registered by the secretary.

To indicate the name of the subject or course, I've often heard after "matricularse" prepositions "**de**" and "**en**" (at least In Spain both of them are very common) so you can hear things like:

> No me he matriculado en esa asignatura.
>
> No me he matriculado de esa asignatura.

The **second** meaning is to register the number plate of a car.

> No puedes sacar el coche del concesionario sin matricularlo antes.